# Output Worksheet Names into a table in ACCESS VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the below code to get all the Sheetnames of a selected workbook. How do I get all the names of the sheets and import them into a table in the Access Database?

```vb
Public Sub PickSheets1(fileName As String)

    Dim objExc As Object
    Dim objWbk As Object
    Dim objWsh As Object
       
    SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO Sheets Table (Sheets) Values (objWbk.Worksheets.Name)"
    Set TabInsert = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("Sheets Table")
    Set TabFields = TabInsert.CreateField("Sheets")
    
    Set objExc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWbk = objExc.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Set objWsh = objWbk.Worksheets.Name
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLInsert
    
    'For Each objWsh In objWbk.Worksheets
        'TabFields("Sheets").Value objWsh.Name
        
    Set objWsh = Nothing
    objWbk.Close
    Set objWbk = Nothing
    objExc.Quit
    Set objExc = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So from within MSAccess you can run this code.  Its uses DAO to add the sheet name to the table.  Assumes that the table 'Sheets Table' with column 'SheetName' already exists.

call loadSheetNames("C:Path\Workbook.xlsx")

```
Function loadSheetNames(pstrWB As String)
    
    ' Access
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
    ' Excel
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Sheets Table")
    
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xl.Workbooks.Open(pstrWB)
    
    For Each xlWS In xlWB.Sheets
        Debug.Print xlWS.NAME
        rst.AddNew
        rst("SheetName") = xlWS.NAME
        rst.update
    Next
        
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing
    
End Function
```

If you want to run the code from within Excel, I can give you that as well.